# Can't call method of derived class - compiler identifies object instance as base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, compiler-errors, base-class

I am getting a compiler error when calling a method defined in a derived class. The compiler seems to think that the object I am referring to is of a base class type:

```
weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(WeaponBuilder(KNIFE)
.name("Thief's Dagger")
.description("Knife favored by Thieves")
.attack(7)    // error: class Builder has no member called attack 
.cost(10)     // error: class Builder has no member called cost
.build());
```

Indeed, `Builder` doesn't contain either `attack` or `cost`:

```
class Builder
{
protected:

    string m_name;
    string m_description;

public:

    Builder();
    virtual ~Builder();
    virtual GameComponent* build() const = 0;

    Builder& name(string);
    Builder& description(string);
};
```

But the derived class `WeaponBuilder` does:

```
enum WeaponType { NONE, KNIFE, SWORD, AXE, WAND };

class WeaponBuilder : public Builder
{
    int m_cost;
    int m_attack;
    int m_magic;

    WeaponType m_type;

public:

    WeaponBuilder();
    WeaponBuilder(WeaponType);
    ~WeaponBuilder();

    GameComponent* build() const;

    // should these be of reference type Builder or WeaponBuilder?
    WeaponBuilder& cost(int); 
    WeaponBuilder& attack(int);
    WeaponBuilder& magic(int);

};
```

I am not sure why the compiler cannot find the `attack` or `cost` method in the `WeaponBuilder` class, as it is clearly present. I am also not sure why it recognizes the object as an instance of the base class `Builder`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It cannot find it because both `name` and `description` return a `Builder&` instead of a `WeaponBuilder&`, hence those other methods are not there. There is no clear solution for your code, other than casting everywhere.

You could rewrite the entire thing using *CRTP* and get ride of your problems, but its a significant change. Something among the lines of:

```
template< typename Derived >
class builder
{
    Derived& name( std::string const& name ){ /*store name*/, return *derived(); }

    Derived* derived(){ return static_cast< Derived* >( this ); }
};

class weapon_builder : builder< weapon_builder >
{
    weapon_builder& attack( int ){ /*store attack*/ return *this; }

    GameComponent* build() const{ return something; }
};
```

Note that with this approach all `virtual` methods should go away, and you lose the ability to reference a plain `builder` as it is no longer a common base type but a class template.

Comment: I see the problem, since I am returning a reference to Builder after the method call to to `name` and `description`. Drats.

Comment: Does this pattern work with more than one object inheriting the `Builder` class?  My idea is to use a `Builder` for each complex object in the game.

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, it works, you can use this pattern to create different _builders_ all sharing the same _implicit_ interface. Note however that there is nothing in common between those types other than that _implicit_ interface, they are otherwise totally unrelated types.

Comment: I implemented the above, but when I call the members for `name` and `description` defined in the templated class when creating a WeaponBuilder object in main, I get a "symbol not found" error.

Comment: @Dylan: _"symbol not found"_ as in a _linker_ error? What's the complete error message?

Comment: "Builder<WeaponBuilder>::name(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:       _main in main.o - symbol not found

Comment: Will post in a new question.

Comment: @Dylan: So much for complete... Looks like you have declared but not defined the `name` function. Check if you have defined it out of class and missed qualification.

Comment: Sorry, but that was the complete message when using XCode (GNU compiler). I defined the two methods for `name` and `description` in a separate implementation file - perhaps because it is templated this is the issue?

Comment: @Dylan: Oh yes, yes it is, _template_ methods must be defined in header files.

Answer (score 1):

Your intention is probably something along these lines:

```
weapon = dynamic_cast<Weapon*>(dynamic_cast<WeaponBuilder &>(WeaponBuilder(KNIFE)
.name("Thief's Dagger")
.description("Knife favored by Thieves"))
.attack(7)    
.cost(10)     
.build());
```

Comment: This eliminated the error when calling the `attack` method, but it still results in a compiler error at `cost` for me.